# Classic ASP SQLNCLI connection string returns empty recordsets that worked fine with SQLOLEDB

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, ado, recordset

Trying to switch to SQLNCLI so I can use varchar(max) fields in my ASP application.  No records are returned from a query that worked fine under SQLOLEDB.

The connection string opens as follows:

```
ConnStr="Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=129.118.139.78,8888;Server=UWCTest;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;DataTypeCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=true;"
oConn.Open connStr
```

and the code to get the recordset is as follows:

```
sSQL="usp_tutors_active_select"

Set dbCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")    
Set dbCommand.ActiveConnection = oConn  
dbCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 
dbCommand.Commandtext=sSQL  


set oRST=dbCommand.Execute

Response.Write orst("firstname")
do while not datacommand1.EOF
    Response.Write "<option value=" & orst("firstname") & ">" & orst("firstname")

    orst.MoveNext
loop
```

Comment: What does orst.RecordCount say in both cases? Changing provider should make no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to install the SQLCNI provider on the server; the actual error that was masked by the apparently empty recordset was actually a "provider not found."

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `SET NO COUNT ON` to the top of `usp_tutors_active_select`. I seem to remember having this issue before.

Comment: Hmm, maybe not actually. I remember it causing some issue with ADO but perhaps not that. This discussion may be relevant. http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31753706/transactions-in-sql-serve.aspx I'd probably use SQL Profiler to investigate - capture the row count column.